# I want to hide a parent element if the image contained is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with a cell that contains a div to hold an image.

What I want to do is if the image itself has an empty src value or if there is an error on loading the image, to then set the display of the parent cell to none.

The table will actually list a series of images in the page and not all will be mepty or show an error.

The code below shows the table cell... info within {} are in fact dynamic data values passed through as text literals. If the value for "img src" is in error or empty then I want to set the display for ID of the TD to "none.

```
<td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top; width: 400px;" id="{tag_itemid}">
<div class="image_container">
    <div class="border"> 
        <div class="boxSep">
            <div style="width: 250px; height: 250px; border-radius: 15px;" class="imgLiquidFill imgLiquid imgLiquid_bgSize imgLiquid_ready"> 
                <a title="{tag_name_nolink}" target="_blank" href="{tag_itemurl_nolink}" style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%;"> 
                    <img src="{tag_image (small)_value}" /> 
                 </a> 
             </div>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Would also like to handle situation where I have just the single table on my page with 2 iamges in the table each in a div and I want to set display=none for each DIV subject to image src being invalid URL or if src="" - see example below

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <div class="image_container_no_rollover icg_4" id="hldr1">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="">
        </div>
        <div id="hldr2" >
            <img style="border: 0px none;" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/250/" alt="">
        </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("td").each(function () {
        var $img = $(this).find("img");
        if ($img[0] === undefined) return;

        var td = this;
        $(this).find("img").on("error", function () {
            $(td).css("display", "none");
        });
    });
});
```

Check it out: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vqj0xwva/5/)

Comment: Would also like to know how to change the script if this is the only table on the page and there are 2 separate images that I wish to check as above on each image separately hiding the div holding each image

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve that. For instance:

```
$('td').each(function() {
    if($(this).find('img').attr('src') == "your evaluator here"){
        $(this).css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

Of course, make sure the whole DOM has been loaded before running that code.

Answer (score 0):

I found someone who was able to provide me with the required solution for which you can see the working results below for both cases with much simpler examples.

In answering the first part... Hiding all table cells checking each image within each cell and hiding that cell if the image specified is invalid or if the src=""

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("table").find("img").each(function(){
    if(!$(this).attr("src")){
        $(this).closest("td").hide();
    }else{
        var image = new Image(); 
        image.src = $(this).attr("src");
        if (image.width == 0) {
            $(this).closest("td").hide();
        }
    }
});
```

});

Check it out: [JSFiddle] (http://jsfiddle.net/gregt57/wke7pbgm/11/)

Answer (score 0):

In Answering the second part of my question... Hiding any element where its child contained an invalid image or where src=""

```
$(function() {
 $("#tbl01").find("img").each(function(){
  if(!$(this).attr("src")){
    $(this).parent().hide();
  }else{
   $(this).load(function(){
    // ... loaded  
   }).error(function(){
    // ... not loaded
    $(this).parent().hide();
   });
  }
 });
});
```

Check it out at [[JSFiddle]](http://jsfiddle.net/gregt57/6s1y70bg/4/)